# Dynamic Sidebar with Rails layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance, i want to have my sidebar to have several dynamic content. Using other method will lead me to put query codes into View, which is not a good idea at all. I would like to keep any query in my Controller.

Currently as i know there are several ff. method:

Render a shared partial -> No where to put the query

```
render :partial => "shared/sidebar"
```

Content For -> Additional details in the comment

```
<%= yield :sidebar %>
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <a href="http://www.netscape.com">Netscape</a><br>
  <a href="http://www.lycos.com">Lycos</a><br>
  <a href="http://www.walmart.com">Wal Mart</a><br>
<% end %>
```

3rd is write it directly to the layout file.

So how should I make this work?

Comment: "Content For -> Still it's in the view" Why? IMHO this is the way you can do this and still have all Query's in Controller, why should you need a Query in the view this way?

Comment: Basically Base on my understanding. It moved to controller's view. But if it's like that I will need to put the query code in every controller and put the content_for at every view that I want to display the sidebar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IF you want this in every view, you can place the method that populates the necessary data in application_controller and use a before_filter to trigger it.

```
before_filter :load_sidebar

def load_sidebar
  @data = Thingy.find(:all)
end
```

Then your partial or content_for element checks for @data and processes.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to reduce the amount of code in your `application_controller.rb`, you may want to consider using the [Cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) gem.

This would allow you to define your 'query' in a separate cell controller, and you would render the content for it using something like `render_cell :sidebar, :myquery` inside your view.